# Angular route changes briefly show content that should be hidden

Tags: angularjs

I have a view like so...

```
<section ng-controller="ProfileController">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="!result.success">
        {{result.message}}
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-show="result.success">
        <h1>{{result.profile.username}}</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I access the full url directly, the first div never appears unnecessarily. However, if I click a link to another route and then back I see the alert box briefly before Angular applies the service result.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this behaviour by either using `ng-bind` instead of expression binding or by resolving all necessary data first.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"><br>
  Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
</div>
```

Quote from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind):

> It is preferrable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} when a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

**Or**

[**Resolve**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654195/http-request-before-angularjs-app-initialises/19654889#19654889)