# How to prevent screen flickering with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've multiple directives which fetch their data from the database. In one case I have all the directives in one screen. This means that when the screen is loading each dropdown/field is filled one by one: first you see field A being field, then field B get's his value, then field C, etc. etc. I don't want this, I want that all the data is displayed at once.

How can I achieve this?

Here is one example of a directive. I have about 10 of these directives.

```
app.directive("environmentDropdown", ['EnvironmentService', function (EnvironmentService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select class="form-control" data-ng-options="e.Id as e.Name for e in environments"></select>',
        scope: {
        },
        replace:true,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            EnvironmentService.getEnvironments().then(function (response) {
                scope.environments = response;
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: do you have multiple backend calls for every dropdown?

Comment: @martijn did you try the answer i gave you? did it work?

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose I am using [ng Cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak)

It makes the elements, after which you place the tag invisible until the whole page is loaded

Comment: In all my directives I have added `ng-cloak` into the template. When loading my page, I still see all the fields getting filled one by one, instead of all at once.

Comment: did you add an !important after the ng cloak display:none css rule?

Comment: Yes, I've copied the css class from the documentation, which included the `!important` part..

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch all data before the view is loaded:

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'MyCtrl',resolve: {
        myData: function($q,$http){
            var deffered = $q.defer();

                // make your http request here 
                // store the result in a shared service

            return deffered.promise;
        }
    }}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

myData could then be injected where needed, containing the data.

See also: [$http request before AngularJS app initialises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654195/http-request-before-angularjs-app-initialises/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not told us how your directives retrieve data, I'll assume you use `$http` requests.

You can do something like this:

```
  var promises = []
  for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    var req = requests[i];
    promises.push( $http.post(url, req) )
  }

  $q.all(promises)
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.fields = data
    })
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do this. I've updated my post with an example of a directive.