# AngularJS Flicker

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with flickering - It is not a problem with AngularJS but with, as I think, my architecture.
Its not a big problem but it would be nice if I could prevent this fickering.

I have a stateProvider which looks like this:

```
controller: 'MyController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                myService: 'myService',
                function(myService, $stateParams) {
                    myService.loadMyDataFromBackend('Parameters');
                },
```

In this **stateProvider** data is loaded over a service and this service (myService) then holds the backend- data. In my View I have a **ng-repeat** which picks up this data from **myService**:

```
<tr my-directive-name my-data="vm.getMyDataOverDirectiveAndControllerFromMyService()"
```

My problem now is the following:

> 1. I view data -> everything is fine
> 2. I leave the view
> 3. I came back to the view: 
>      3.1. old data is viewed for some milliseconds
>      3.2 new data is loaded from backend and hold in myService
>      3.3 ng-repeat picks up new data and show it

So 3.1 and 3.2 causes the flickering. Also **ng-cloak** does not prevent flickering - I guess that ng-cloak checks if (old) data is ok/loaded - the old data is viewed and afterwards new data is received and shown -> ng-cloak in this case has no chance to prevent flickering.

My question now would be if there is any possibility to prevent this flickering in my case?

Thanks a lot!

**[EDIT]**
This is my whole resolver, I would be thankful if someone could give me a hint what do do in order to prevent flickering:

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('myproject.schedule')
    .config(configure);

configure.$inject = ['$stateProvider']; 

function configure($stateProvider) {

     $stateProvider
        .state(getXYState());

    ////////////

     function (getXYState() {
        var state = {
            name: 'auth.name',
            url: '/my/path',
            templateUrl: 'app/myhtmlpath/myhtml.html',
            controller: 'MyController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                myService: 'myService',
                function(myService, $stateParams, $q) {
                    myService.getData('...');
                }
            }
        }
        return state;
    };
};
})();
```

Comment: use masking when loading a data from a service and unmask it when data is loaded. so it wont look like flickering.

Comment: Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker
Have you tried this ?

Comment: You should load the data into the model only once it is returned from your service. Check those two questions for more info and examples: [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker) and [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672902/how-to-prevent-screen-flickering-with-angularjs)