# Problems using $http inside a Service

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic data Service which will be used across Controllers. But I'm having an issue grabbing some data that's been added via `$http`.

Service:

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.dropdownData = {
        contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
        industries: {},
    };

    $http.get('/json').success(function(resp){
        _this.dropdownData.industries = resp.industries; 
    });
}]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('SignupController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'FormService', function($scope, $http, $state, FormService) {

    console.log(FormService.dropdownData); // Shows full object incl industries
    console.log(FormService.dropdownData.industries); // empty object {}

}]);
```

How do I get `FormService.dropdownData.industries` in my controller?

Comment: can you atleast paste the structure of that object, or plunkr example would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your service and use $Http.get inside that like below

```
_this.getindustries = function (callback) {
        return $http.get('/json').success(function(resp){
            _this.dropdownData.industries = resp.industries; 
            callback(_this.dropdownData)
      });
    };
```

In your controller need to access it like below.

```
 angular.module('core').controller('myController', ['$scope', 'FormService', function ($scope, FormService) {
   FormService.getDropdownData(function (dropdownData) {
       console.log(dropdownData); // Shows full object incl industries
       console.log(dropdownData.industries); // object {}
   });
```

} ]);

Comment: Thanks, I felt like this was the most elegant and reusable answer.

Comment: Also better you can move your http calls to a separate service use your service to access the http. that will make more maintanable code. given below a sample for ajaxcalls.

Comment: (function(angular) {
    angular.module('onboardingApp').service('ajaxService',function($http) {
        var self=this;
        self.get=function(options) {
            options.type='get';
            if(options.blockUI==undefined) {
                options.blockUI=true;
            }
            return $.ajax(options);
        };
        self.post=function(options) {
            options.type='post';
            if(options.blockUI==undefined) {
                options.blockUI=true;
            }
            return $.ajax(options);
        };
    });
})(angular);

Answer (score 3):

Create a service like below

```
appService.factory('Service', function ($http) {
        return {
            getIndustries: function () {
                return $http.get('/json').then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Call in controller

```
appCtrl.controller('personalMsgCtrl', ['$scope', 'Service', function ($scope, Service) {
    $scope.Industries = Service.getIndustries();
}]);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Note that Nitin transformed the original service into a factory, which behaves slightly different.

Comment: Yes it work a bit different, please look at this article
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 1):

Given that your console log shows the correct object, that shows your service is functioning properly. Only one small mistake you have made here. You need to access the `data` attributes in your return promise.

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var _this = this;
  _this.dropdownData = {
     contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
     industries: {},
 };

 $http.get('/json').success(function(resp){
    //note that this is resp.data.industries, NOT resp.industries
    _this.dropdownData.industries = resp.data.industries; 
   });
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're data is indeed existing and there are no problems with the server, there are quite a few possible solutions

#### Returning a promise

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var _this = this;
  _this.dropdownData = {
    contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
    industries: {},
  };

  _this.dropdownData.industries = $http.get('/json');
}]);

//Controller
FormService.industries
.then(function(res){
    $scope.industries = res.industries
});
```

#### Resolving with routeProvider / ui-route

See: [$http request before AngularJS app initialises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654195/http-request-before-angularjs-app-initialises/19654889#19654889)

---

You could also write a function to initialize the service when the application starts running. At the end of the day, it is about waiting for the data to be loaded by using a promise. If you never heard about promises before, inform yourself first.

Comment: thanks, i understand what a promise it, but it was just weird to me how `FormService.dropdownData.industries` returned an empty obj, while `FormService.dropdownData` returned the full object including all values for `industries`

Answer (score 0):

The industries object will be populated at a later point in time when the $http call returns.  In the meantime you can still bind to the reference in your view because you've preserved the reference using angular.copy. When the $http call returns, the view will automatically be updated.

It is also a good idea to allow users of your service to handle the event when the $http call returns. You can do this by saving the $promise object as a property of industries:

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.dropdownData = {
        contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
        industries: {},
    };

    _this.dropdownData.industries.$promise = $http.get('/json').then(function(resp){
               // when the ansyc call returns, populate the object, 
               // but preserve the reference
               angular.copy( resp.data.industries, _this.dropdownData.industries); 
               return _this.dropdownData.industries;
           });


}]);
```

Controller

```
    app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, FormService){
              // you can bind this to the view, even though the $http call has not returned yet
              // the view will update automatically since the reference was preserved
              $scope.dropdownData = FormService.dropdownData;

              // alternatively, you can hook into the $http call back through the $promise
              FormService.dropdownData.industries.$promise.success(function(industries) {
                     console.log(industries);
              });
    });
```