# Load configuration data in Angular Applicatoin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular application, I want to load some user specific configuration data from server, if user authorized. This data will use all over the application. I have implemented cookie base token authentication. How can I delay application until this data loading complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `resolve` in route. Example from [ng-doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    resolve: {
      // I will cause a 1 second delay
      delay: function($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
        return delay.promise;
      }
    }
  });
```

Instead of timeout promise you can return any promise what you wish.
In this case your controller will be started after `route.resolve` promise resolving.

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654889/3323304) answer. It looks like very relevant for your case.

Comment: If we use this approach, then we need to do something defined for all the routes right? Is there a way to do it in one place without rewriting it again and again?

Comment: Yes, you need set it in each route, because a set of resolving promises can be different in each route. But you can create a function or a service which creates a route with your params like url, template controller and predefined properties like authorization resolving if you need it everywhere